# Java AutoComplete : Popup on every KeyPress

Tags: java, autocomplete, ide, keypress

I am using Java `AutoComplete` library to make an IDE. I was wondering how can I make the popup window show on every `KeyPress`. I have tried :

```
autoCompletion.setAutoCompleteSingleChoices(false);
textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            autoCompletion.doCompletion();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

But it just doesn't work how I wanted. I need it to work this way :

[Demonstration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQGNA.gif)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: The animated gif shows us how you want it to work, but you need to explain what "doesn't work how I wanted" means. So, what went wrong?

Comment: 1. It shows up on every single press, even when i haven't started pressing anything -> when i'm on second line and I want to skip line, it won't let me do that. - I just need something that work like in the gif